# Use variables in different methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

At this time I need to use three variables in three different methods with the respective file in the view, but I don't want to define each variable in each method.

How can I define the variable just once and have access to the variables from all the three methods?

Those are the methods:

```
def pendientes
end

def proceso
end

def finalizadas
end
```

Those are the three variables:

```
@pendientes     = Support.where("estado = ?", 1)
@procesos       = Support.where("estado = ?", 2)
@finalizadas    = Support.where("estado = ?", 3)
```

How do I need to define the variables to do it?

Comment: Why don't you want to define each variable in each method? Are you having refactoring problems?

Comment: Is just because I dont want to define it in each method, I think is better to do it with another way, with less code

Comment: Are these three methods in a controller?

Comment: Yes these are in the same controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're working in the context of a controller, you could do something like this:

```
class MyController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :initialize_variables

  def pendientes
  end

  def proceso
  end

  def finalizadas
  end

  private

    def initialize_variables
      @pendientes = Support.where(estado: 1)
      @procesos = Support.where(estado: 2)
      @finalizadas = Support.where(estado: 3)
    end
end
```

**Update:**

If you roll with a `before_filter`, it may be a good idea to add `only: [:pendientes, :proceso, :finalizadas]` so that future actions added to the controller don't initialize the three variables.

Another option would be to delete the `before_filter` call and just invoke the `initialize_variables` method from each of the three existing actions.

Comment: I don't think before_filter is the right case here. What if more actions to be added in this controller? You'll add unnecessary burdens to them. Then use `:only` to separate them?

Comment: `:only` would work. I don't think the extra database calls would add much burden if more actions got added, though. It may have been better to just call `initialize_variables` from each of the three actions that currently exist. I'll update my answer to mention the alternatives.